# How do I set the bar width static in a horizontal bar chart in ios-charts?

Tags: swift, ios-charts

How can you set the bar width on a horizontal bar chart in the ios-charts library? It seems that the width is based off the size of the frame drawn for the chart. Therefore it spaces each bar to a size that almost fills the container. Is there any way to override this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes I remember it will calculate the bar width to fit for the screen.

There are two properties:

1. barSpace
2. groupSpace

These two defines the bar width and the space for grouped bars. It is a little obscured to understand by its name, so you need to read the code.

There is also a `barSpace` property inside the barDataSet you could use to custimze:

```
/// space indicator between the bars in percentage of the whole width of one value (0.15 == 15% of bar width)
public var barSpace: CGFloat = 0.15
```

The groupSpace can be customized in barChartData:

```
private var _groupSpace = CGFloat(0.8)

/// The spacing is relative to a full bar width
public var groupSpace: CGFloat
{
    get
    {
        return _groupSpace
    }
    set
    {
        _groupSpace = newValue
    }
}
```

Overriding them requires you have a better understanding, especially you want to override the renderer.

Comment: Can you have different bar width for each bar? Ie can the bar width be calculated dynamically for each data point?

Comment: @Suraya No I don't think so. It's set for all bars.

Comment: do you have an idea for how I could go about implementing this?

Comment: well you have to understand how the library works and start override